# how to use same routes and controller for different components codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter to create different components.
Each component belongs to a city. e.g london will have 3 component/functions 
I want to create url  like below

```
mydomain.com/london/component1
mydomain.com/london/component2
mydomain.com/london/component3
```

Similarly for any generic city

```
mydomain.com/city/component1
mydomain.com/city/component2
mydomain.com/city/component3
```

I want to use one controller and its function for this purpose. 
how can i create routes for this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

*in `config.php`*

```
/*here  mydomain.com*/

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';
```

*Your `route.php` should be like this:*

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'city/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'city/$1/$2';

$route['default_controller'] = 'city';

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

*Your City Controller :*

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class City extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construtct()
    {
        parent::__construtct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function london($component=NULL)
    {
      echo $component;die;

    }
}
```

Your links :

```
 /* index */
 mydomain.com/

 /* for london output : component */
 mydomain.com/london/component
```

Comment: have u checked my answer, is it helpful for you?

Comment: $route['(:any)'] = 'city/$1';
@pardeep will it not effect all other url's in my project?

Comment: of course it affects, assuming here it is only for one controller, if u want to it for particular controller u have to add controller name or any string whatever u like before (:any)